# Defining constraint on prior with potential class

Tags: python, markov-chain-montecarlo, prior, pymc

I have written an MCMC code in order to estimate parameters Xpos, Ypos, MASS and concentration with a set of input data `gal_pos`, `observed_g` (the parameter which the model gets compared) and the uncertainty in this parameter, `shearerr`. The problem is that the MCMC chain will break down if MASS would be less than $10^{13}$ due to the properties of the likelihood function `nfwmodeltools.shearprofile_like` and it follows the **exponential** and **LogNormal** prior shape. In order to put the constraint on `MASS` and `concentration`, I have defined a potential class but I don't know how it should be used and where, in order to enforce `MASS` to follow lower bound.

```
import pymc as pm
import nfwmodeltools
import numpy as np
import math
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import expon
import astropy.cosmology
from astropy.cosmology import FlatLambdaCDM
cos = FlatLambdaCDM(H0=70, Om0=0.3)
from astropy import units as u
cosmo=nfwmodeltools.global_cosmology()
print "Reading input catalogues as observed values......."
shear=np.loadtxt('/vol/cluster.shear.cat') #my shear catalogue
data=np.loadtxt('/vol/Extended.MockFidSurvey.dat')
for i in range(len(data[:,0])):
    if (i<1):
        gal_pos=np.array([data[i,0],data[i,1]])
        observed_g=np.array([shear[i,2],shear[i,3]])
        shearerr=np.array([data[i,5]])
    else:
        gal_pos=np.vstack((gal_pos, np.array([data[i,0],data[i,1]]))) 
        observed_g=np.vstack((observed_g, np.array([shear[i,2],shear[i,3]]))) 
        shearerr=np.vstack((shearerr,np.array([data[i,5]])))


g_err=shearerr.reshape(shearerr.shape[0],)
print "Reading redshift distributions of galaxies, where we will marginalize over this parameter when we will compute beta and rho_c_over_sigma_c....."
redshift_pdf=np.loadtxt('/vol/data/pdf.redshift.MockFidSurvey.dat')
#Normalize the probability
zpdf=np.array([redshift_pdf[j,:]/sum(redshift_pdf[j,:]) for j in xrange(gal_pos.shape[0])] )
#The whole range of redshift
z=np.arange(0,1.5,0.001)
z_halo=0.15
x=1*u.Mpc
angular_separation=(x*180)/np.pi/ cos.angular_diameter_distance(z_halo) 
print "convert radian to degree for angular separation in the redshift of cluster and compute 1 Mpc seperation in degree:"
print angular_separation
#one of the input parameter for loglikelihood
rho_crit=cosmo.cosmology.rho_crit(z_halo)
#prepare the requirement for the mcmc model
print "We multiply the probability with the computed function for the given array z to marginalize over z"
rho_c_over_sigma_c=np.dot(zpdf,cosmo.cosmology.RhoCrit_over_SigmaC(z, z_halo))
print rho_c_over_sigma_c.shape
beta=np.dot(zpdf, cosmo.cosmology.beta_s(z, z_halo))       
print "Defining the model as nfw model for MCMC..."
def nfw(gal_pos,observed_g,g_err,rho_crit,rho_c_over_sigma_c,beta):
    """
    gal_pos:background galaxy positions
    gt: tangential reduced shear
    g_err: shear error
    rho_crit: critical density
    rho_c_over_sigma_c: critical density over critical surface mass density
    beta:Dds/Ds
    """
    @pm.stochastic(dtype=np.float, observed=False, trace=True)
    def Xpos(value=25.4,x_l=25.25,x_h=25.55):
        """The probable region of the position of halo centre"""
        if ((value>x_h) or (value<x_l)):
            return -np.inf
        else:
            return -np.log(x_h-x_l+1)        

    @pm.stochastic(dtype=np.float, observed=False, trace=True)
    def Ypos(value=-10.01,y_l=-10.3,y_h=-9.9):
        """The probable region of the position of halo centre"""
        if ((value>y_h) or (value<y_l)):
            return -np.inf
        else:
            return -np.log(y_h-y_l+1)
    #------------------------------------------------------------
    # Based on a simulated or observed mass function we adopt a simple exponential prior  
    @pm.stochastic
    def MASS(value=math.pow(10,14), rate = math.pow(10,15)):
        """mass is a stochastic parameter with exponential distribution.p(M)~exp(-M/10^15)"""
        return pm.exponential_like(value, rate)
    @pm.potential
    def MASS_bound(MASS=MASS):
        if ((MASS >= math.pow(10,13)) and (MASS < math.pow(10,16))):
           return 0.0
        else:
           return -np.inf

    #MASS=math.pow(10,30)*pm.Exponential('mass', beta=math.pow(10,15))
    @pm.deterministic
    def sigma( name='sigma_concentration' ,M=MASS, trace=True, plot= True): 
       if M < 10**15:
           return .09
       else:
           return .06

    cExpected = 5.26/(1+z_halo)*(MASS/math.pow(10,14))**(-.1) # based on Neto et al. 2007
    concentration = pm.Lognormal("concentration", cExpected, sigma)
    @pm.potential
    def concentration_bound(concentration=concentration):
        if (concentration <= 20):
           return 0.0
        else:
           return -np.inf

    model_pars=[Xpos, Ypos, MASS, concentration]
    @pm.stochastic( name='reduced_shear', dtype=float,observed=True, trace = True )
    def reduced_shear(value=observed_g, model_pars=model_pars):
       Xpos=model_pars[0]
       Ypos=model_pars[1]
       mass=model_pars[2]
       conc=model_pars[3]
       #seperation in the scale of Mpc
       dist=np.sqrt((gal_pos[:,0]-Xpos)**2+(gal_pos[:,1]-Ypos)**2)*angular_separation
       phi=np.arctan2((gal_pos[:,1]-Ypos), (gal_pos[:,0]-Xpos))
       gtan=-(value[:,0]*np.cos(2*phi)+value[:,1]*np.sin(2*phi))
       gcros=-value[:,0]*np.sin(2*phi)+value[:,1]*np.cos(2*phi)
       d=np.vstack((dist,gtan,g_err,beta,rho_c_over_sigma_c))
       #concatenate input data and sort data based on their distance from cluster center
       ndata=np.array(sorted(d.T, key=lambda  l:l[0]))
       #choose objects closer than 2.5 Mpc to the cluster center
       ndata=ndata[ndata[:,0]<=2.5*angular_separation]
       #binning data again based on their distance
       bins = np.linspace(ndata[0,0], ndata[-1,0], 10)
       #compute the mean in each bin for different input parameters
       digitized = np.digitize(ndata[:,0], bins)
       bin_r_mpc= np.array([ndata[digitized == i,0].mean() for i in range(1, len(bins))])
       bin_shear= np.array([ndata[digitized == i,1].mean() for i in range(1, len(bins))])
       bin_shearerr= np.array([ndata[digitized == i,2].mean() for i in range(1, len(bins))])
       avebeta= ndata[:,3].mean() 
       avebeta2=(ndata[:,3]**2).mean()
       ave_rho_c_over_sigma_c=ndata[:,4].mean() 
       loglikelihood = nfwmodeltools.shearprofile_like(mass,
                                                       conc,
                                                       bin_r_mpc,
                                                       bin_shear,
                                                       bin_shearerr,
                                                       avebeta,
                                                       avebeta2,
                                                       rho_crit,
                                                       ave_rho_c_over_sigma_c)
       return loglikelihood
    return locals()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    M = pm.MCMC(nfw(gal_pos,observed_g,g_err,rho_crit,rho_c_over_sigma_c,beta),db='pickle',dbname='NFWTracer.pickle')
    M.use_step_method(pm.AdaptiveMetropolis, M.model_pars ,verbose=1)
    mass = M.step_method_dict[M.MASS][0]
    M.isample(100000,10000,100)
    [pm.Matplot.plot(s) for s in [ M.MASS, M.Xpos, M.Ypos, M.concentration]]
```

I will appreciate if somebody give me advise that where it should be used and which kind of change I need to make in my code..

running the code with above configuration I got this error:

```
ERROR: ZeroProbability: Potential concentration_bound forbids its parents' current values [pymc.PyMCObjects]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MASS_NFW_MCMC.py", line 148, in <module>
    M = pm.MCMC(nfw(gal_pos,observed_g,g_err,rho_crit,rho_c_over_sigma_c,beta),db='pickle',dbname='NFWTracer.pickle')
  File "MASS_NFW_MCMC.py", line 102, in nfw
    def concentration_bound(concentration=concentration):
  File "/vol/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/InstantiationDecorators.py", line 215, in potential
    return instantiate_pot(__func__)
  File "/vol/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/InstantiationDecorators.py", line 208, in instantiate_pot
    return Potential(parents=parents, **kwds)
  File "/vol/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/PyMCObjects.py", line 275, in __init__
    if not isinstance(self.logp, float):
  File "/vol/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/PyMCObjects.py", line 327, in get_logp
    raise ZeroProbability(self.errmsg)
pymc.Node.ZeroProbability: Potential concentration_bound forbids its parents' current values
```